# Hive Self Join tables using Sort Merge Bucket Map(SMB Map) Join : Slow Processing

Tags: hive

I have the below query an it takes forever for the mapper to complete.

I am trying to do self join between table bucketed and sorted and the mapper never reduces . I get 8192 mappers and 0 reducers for stage 1. The mapper s in stage 1 never finish and error out.

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
site_id BIGINT,
user_id BIGINT
)
CLUSTERED BY (user_id)
SORTED BY (user_id)
INTO 8192 BUCKETS;

SET hive.enforce.bucketing = true;
SET hive.enforce.sorting = true;


INSERT  OVERWRITE TABLE test
SELECT  
        distinct
        u.uuid, 
        sd.slice_id
FROM table A u


--- MAPPER NEVER COMPLETES THE BELOW QUERY. EXPALIN PLAN SHOWS Sorted Merge Bucket Map Join Operator

SET hive.auto.convert.sortmerge.join=true;
SET hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin = true;
SET hive.optimize.bucketmapjoin.sortedmerge = true;
SET hive.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.BucketizedHiveInputFormat;
SET hive.auto.convert.sortmerge.join.bigtable.selection.policy = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.TableSizeBasedBigTableSelectorForAutoSMJ;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;

CREATE TABLE test
AS
SELECT  /*+ MAPJOIN(u2) */
        u1.user_id, 
        u1.site_id as site_id_a, 
        u2.site_id as site_id_b
FROM    test_tmp   u1 
join    test_tmp   u2
ON      u1.user_id = u2.user_id
WHERE   COALESCE(u1.site_id,0) <> COALESCE(u2.site_id,0) ;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For anybody to help, you should post the error message you get at the end of the map stage. Also, how big is the table ? And how many nodes is your cluster ? If your table is not big and you don't have many nodes, 8192 buckets may be too many

Comment: I don't get any error, the mappers runs for 16 hours and complete only 7%. I finally kill the job. I have around 3 billion records and have 320 nodes in my cluster.

Comment: @sanj Did u found the solution to above problem ?